# Split list on None and record index

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list which can contain both `None`s and `datetime` objects. I need to split this in sublists of consecutive `datetime` objects and need to record the index of the first `datetime` object of this sublist in the original list.

E.g., I need to be able to turn

```
original = [None, datetime(2013, 6, 4), datetime(2014, 5, 12), None, None, datetime(2012, 5, 18), None]
```

into:

```
(1, [datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 12, 0, 0)])
(5, [datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 18, 0, 0)])
```

I have tried two approaches. One using `find`:

```
binary = ''.join('1' if d else '0' for d in original)
end = 0
start = binary.find('1', end)
while start > -1:
    end = binary.find('0', start)
    if end < 0:
        end = len(binary)
    dates = original[start:end]
    print (start, dates)
    start = binary.find('1', end)
```

and one using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
for key, group in groupby(enumerate(original), lambda x: x[1] is not None):
    if key:
        group = list(group)
        start = group[0][0]
        dates = [t[1] for t in group]
        print (start, dates)
```

But both don't seem overly Pythonic to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use a generator to produce the elements, encapsulating the grouping:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def indexed_date_groups(it):
    indexed = enumerate(it)
    for i, elem in indexed:
        if elem is not None:
           yield (
             i, [elem] + [v for i, v in takewhile(
                 lambda v: v[1] is not None, indexed)])
```

Here I used [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to produce the sublist once we find an initial not-`None` object.

You can do the same with `itertools.groupby()` still, of course:

```
from itertools import groupby

def indexed_date_groups(it):
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(it), lambda v: v[1] is not None):
        if key:
           indices, elems = zip(*group)
           yield indices[0], elems
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(indexed_date_groups(original))
[(1, [datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 12, 0, 0)]), (5, [datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 18, 0, 0)])]
>>> original = [None, datetime(2013, 6, 4), datetime(2014, 5, 12), None, None, datetime(2012, 5, 18), None]
>>> for index, group in indexed_date_groups(original):
...     print index, group
... 
1 [datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 12, 0, 0)]
5 [datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 18, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: That's great! I've never seen that particular `itertools` function before. I was working on a solution with `filter` and trying to split the list after the fact. This is MUCH cleaner.

Comment: Do you do `v[1] is not None` because it is more explicit than just `v[1]` or because some datetime objects can evaluate to False?  (If so, I wasn't aware that they could.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: explictness; but `datetime.time.min` *is* false. `datetime.datetime.min` is not, so it doesn't play here.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby, count
idx = count()
for key, group in groupby(original, lambda x: x is not None):
    indices, group = zip(*((next(idx), i) for i in group))
    if key:
        print (indices[0], group)
```

Comment: I posted a riff on your answer that tracks the index differently.  I would have left it as a comment, but it was clearer to write code than to explain the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24783682/1322401).  It dispenses with `count` and `zip` and calculates the index directly:

```
from itertools import groupby
idx = 0
for key, group in groupby(original, lambda x: x is not None):
    group = list(group)
    if key:
        print idx, group
    idx += len(group)
```